# Mysql Query Not Giving Output

Tags: php, mysql

Iam newbie to Php and mysql.I have a datetime field in database and upon that datetime field iam generating a report.Here is my query

```
$date = $year."-".$month;
SELECT *FROM table WHERE request_date LIKE '$date%';
```

The month and year variables iam taking from input fields in a form.Here iam concatinating those two variables and passing them in the query.But it retruns nothing.
The stored value in request_date is of formate 2011-02-28.

Kindly help how to do this.

regards;

Comment: Try to echoing `SELECT *FROM table WHERE request_date LIKE '$date%';` what is it echoing?

Comment: First write properly your query, create space between * and FROM `SELECT * FROM`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put space between **`*`** and **`FROM`** like this.

```
$date = $year."-".$month;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE request_date LIKE '$date%';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to query for Year and month field then you could do:

```
SELECT * FROM projects 
WHERE YEAR(request_date) = $year AND MONTH(request_date) = $month
```